# 404 error in C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, http-status-code-404

How can I handle manually the `404 error` in C#?

I want to check some conditions in `404 error` and then redirect it to the proper page.

I know the `web.config` settings, but you can't check conditions in `web.config` file, can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

```
var sr = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
if (sr.GetHttpCode() == 404)
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the HttpStatusCode enumeration, specifically `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`:

Something like:

```
WebException we;
HttpWebResponse errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
if (errorResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    //
}
```

Reference: 
[How can I catch a 404?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949610/c-how-can-i-catch-a-404)

Similar questions:

- [How to properly catch a 404 error in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149208/how-to-properly-catch-a-404-error-in-net)
- [Handling 404's better in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582189/handling-404s-better-in-net)